# Neither weak nor strong or unowned will do during self dismissal?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Is this a valid pattern to avoid being retained after the dismissal?

```
@objc func backButtonTapped() {
    var s: SiteViewController! = self
    navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true, completion: {
        s.dismissCompletion()
        s = nil // break the strong reference to self
    })
}
```

Comment: You can just use `self` in the closure. Once control returns from the closure the reference to `self` will be released. If you did want to use `s` there is no reason to declare it as an implicitly unwrapped optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `self` in the closure. Once control returns from the closure the reference to `self` will be released.

If you did want to use `s` there is no reason to declare it as an implicitly unwrapped optional.  You could just say `var s = self`

Comment: ok, I've crossed fingers, removed my hack and left self implicitly strong
deinit is not called for that VC anyway, so there is a retain cycle elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

This closure should release `s` right once it is executed. I think you can place `self` there without worries

Answer (score -1):

You can do following to avoid retention,

```
@objc func backButtonTapped() {
  navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true, completion: { [weak self] in
       if let strongSelf: SiteViewController = self {
         strongSelf.dismissCompletion()
       } 
   })
}
```

This will make sure there won't be any retention.